# Window models in stream data processing

Tags: large-data, definition, moving-window

Reading about data stream clustering I met the next terms:

- landmark window model,
- sliding window model,
- damped window.

As to sliding window it's clear - oldest data escape the scope, the new data go inside.
But what are the consepts of the other two?

I can suppose that damped window it's like a buffer, that is flushed after filling but some explanation, that I had found, states that dumped uses decreasing weights of data as function of time.

Comment: Isn't "**landmark** data model" be supposed to be based on a "landmark" i.e. any given point, not the specifically the "beginning of times"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From p 1077 of "Advanced Data Mining and Applications: Second International Conference":

A **landmark data model** considers the data in the data stream from the beginning until now.

A **sliding window model**, on the other hand, considers the data from now up to a certain range in the past.

A **damped window model** associates weights with the data in the stream, and gives higher weights to recent data than those in the past.